# Adding variable table name in SQL query while running in Excel VBA

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I need a for loop that will do 2 functions:
1. Increment the numeric value in the table name ("strnum1num2") 12x28 times (01-12 values for num1 and 31-58 values for num2). So table is of the format, saym ab0131
2. The recordset for each iteration should be placed in a sheet that corresponds to num1. Due to this, i'm not sure whether num1 will be declared as integer or string. `enter code here`

I'm in the dark regarding how the numeric variable can be given as table in the SQL query as desired. Below is the skeleton I wrote, but i'couldn't get the query to run.

I also need help in incrementing the sheet value so that the output is copied to sheet(num1+1)

```
Dim w As String
Dim z As Integer

For w = "01" To "02"

    For z = 31 To 32

        sqlQuery = "select parm1 from tab1 & ""w"" & "" & ""z"" & where parm1 in (select parm2 from table2 where parm3 ='O')"

        Set rs = conn.Execute(sqlQuery)

        'Transfer result

        Sheets("w" + 1).Cell(2, "z" - 29).CopyFromRecordset rs

    Next w

Next z
```

The transfer result part is just the logic that I want to implement and not the actual code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm struggling to interpret your requirement *exactly*, but the following loop set up should give you what you need - just tweak it as necessary. Basically, keep the numbers as integers until you create your query text, and format them accordingly at that point:

```
Dim w As Integer
Dim z As Integer

For w = 1 To 2

    For z = 31 To 32

        sqlQuery = "select parm1 from tab1" & Format(w, "00") & z & " where parm1 in (select parm2 from table2 where parm3 ='O')"

        Set rs = conn.Execute(sqlQuery)

        'Transfer result

        Sheets(w + 1).Cell(2, z - 29).CopyFromRecordset rs

    Next z

Next w
```

This creates the following queries:

```
select parm1 from tab10131 where parm1 in (select parm2 from table2 where parm3 ='O')
select parm1 from tab10132 where parm1 in (select parm2 from table2 where parm3 ='O')
select parm1 from tab10231 where parm1 in (select parm2 from table2 where parm3 ='O')
select parm1 from tab10232 where parm1 in (select parm2 from table2 where parm3 ='O')
```

Comment: The aim is to query a certain table that has cyclic information - 28 cycle spread across 12 months, and each cycle-month combination is a unique table. the recordset obtained os to be transferred monthwise onto individual sheets, and recirds for each cycle in a month in distinct columns. I'll give this method a try and see what happens

Comment: Dim w,z as long